# How to run an app on an iPhone simlator with Android Studio on mac?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ios-simulator

I want to get started with flutter. I have downloaded flutter and the Android Studio and XCode. In Android Studio, I can select the ios simulator from the drop down menu, but all that does is turn the simulator on and doesn't actually run my app. I am not sure what else do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Open your app on Xcode, xcode will configure somethings. When you compile from android studio to an iphone emulator, xcode compiles the project, so it needs to configure the project at least once. You may need to go to the project's ios folder and run pod install to install the ios dependencies.